# Unable to set Text on Text Viewer from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

First of all, I am a **newbie**.

I am trying to design a login/Registration system using firebase. Everything is working well, but whenever I'm trying to show the name and address on the TextView, its not showing anything though all infos are updating on database.

Here is my **Profile.java**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
    textViewFullName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewFullName);
    textViewAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
    editTextFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFullName);
    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
    buttonSaveInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveInfo);
    buttonLogOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogOut);

    buttonSaveInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonLogOut.setOnClickListener(this);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
    }

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(); //to use the data of the current user
    textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome "+user.getEmail());

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();//needed to view or input anything from/to database




////////////////Here is my setText code:////////////////////////////

    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();

        //display all the information
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + uInfo.getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: address: " + uInfo.getAddress());

        textViewFullName.setText(uInfo.getName());
        textViewAddress.setText(uInfo.getAddress());
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonLogOut){
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }
    if (v == buttonSaveInfo){
        saveUserInformation();
    }
}

private void saveUserInformation(){
    String name = editTextFullName.getText().toString().trim();
    String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

    UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(name, address);

    //to store data to the individual profiles, I will use the unique id(s) of the logged in firebase user profiles.
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInformation);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Profile Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

and here is my **UserInformation.java**:

```
public class UserInformation {

public String name;
public String address;

public UserInformation(){

}

public UserInformation(String name, String address){
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}
}
```

Comment: uInfo object has nothing inside it that's why textview is not showing anything !

Comment: Between you have written code in the worst way possible . Firebase.getCurrentUser() is a static method .There is no need to call it again and again .

Comment: Thank you. Its working now. And about the coding part, I have started learning android from few days back. So not that much fluent. Could you help me out with any book name or tutorial series?

Comment: Read "The busy coder's guide to Android Development" by Commonsware ! It is the best book you can get for learning Android that too from Beginner to Advanced ! For video lectures , see the videos by Udacity and slidenerd .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new `UserInformation` object using its empty constructor. Therefore its `name` and `address` are null, so when you call `getName()` and `getAddress()` it returns null and prints out an empty value.

Use this constructor to initialise the `name` and `address` values:

```
public UserInformation(String name, String address)
```